# Performance: listen to all form elements changes to sync all dynamic attributes with new data

Tags: javascript, mvvm, javascript-framework

There is a simple form:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> Checkbox
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Task is: **email** field must be displayed only if **checkbox** is checked, and **button** must be displayed only if **email** filled

So, I decided to implement it like this:

1. **email** and **button** must have `data-visible` attribute with display conditions
2. **checkbox** and **email** inputs must be listened to changes
3. Any **checkbox** and **email** changes should run checks to show|hide `data-visible` elements based on conditions

Result is:

```js
// inputs to listen based on id attr (temp solution)
let inputs = form.querySelectorAll('[id]');

// elements to set/unset visibility
let visibles = form.querySelectorAll('[data-visible]');

// Loop all data-visible elements to toggle display: block|none based on evaluated condition
function sync() {
    for (let v of visibles) {
        if(eval(v.getAttribute('data-visible'))) {
            v.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            v.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

// Listen to all inputs changes and sync with new data
for (let input of inputs) {
    input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        sync()
    });
}

sync() // Hide everything that must be hidden on init
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Checkbox
    <input data-visible="checkbox.checked" type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <button data-visible="email.value">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or on [codepen](https://codepen.io/maxcore/pen/ewmOYg)

So, actually, this is only an approach, required/disabled/class attributes also must be toggled based on form data changes

Basically, what I am trying to achieve - is to implement simple MVVM-like approach, but relying on form data rather than JS-model

In real-life task, it turns out, that ~20 of all form elements might be listened for all their changes, and each change will evaluate all ~20 conditions at once to set/unset some attributes

So, the concern is - could it cause some serious memory/cpu issues? Or everything is ok and MVVM-frameworks do nearly the same? Can I go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar before and don't recommend the path you are currently travelling.

**The reasons:**

- You are using eval -- there is an expression: "eval is evil" which is mostly true and you should only use eval if there is no other choice.
- You are looping over all inputs each time even though nothing has changed on most of them. This will cause unnecessary load on the browser as you mentioned

**For the solution:**

- Try putting field in JSON encoded blocks inside the HTML - like:

`<input data-visible="{ 'checkbox-id': { 'prop': 'checked', 'regex': true } }" ... >`

- The above allows for multiple checks per element (you can pick to AND/OR them together)
- parse the data using **JSON.Parse**
- build a reverse lookup object based on ID of any given input -- find all that rely on the input (if this is dynamic this part would be a small issue)
- on input change loop through all dependents recursively and show/hide them

Here is a fiddle implementing something like what you are looking for: [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_wasson/3kbmr5xa/)

Please do let me know if this not what you are looking for.

Comment: Big thx for sharing your experience. As far as I know - "eval is evil" in browser's JS only if we evaluate some data submitted by users. Btw, JSON.Parse approach looks very promising, have to spend some time playing it. Thank you one more time, I'll be back after some sandbox playing)

Comment: @MaxCore The only reason eval is bad in this case is that it also causes strain on the browser because it cannot optimize whatever you are doing. Also enjoy - it's a very fun problem!

Comment: "also causes strain on the browser" - got it) Btw, I can not imagine what more could be said on that topic, I'll mark it accepted, thx again)

Comment: @MaxCore one more thing -- you might be able to optimize the child checks further by checking if the child was already hidden before the recursion part. I'll leave that part up to you.

Comment: If you are interested, you will not believe, but I followed your approach, found a solution to avoid evals (and jsons), make code cleaner, and set only those attributes that was really affected (via reversed lookup object as you said) and ended up with "genius" https://ucssjs.github.io =)

Comment: @MaxCore I also have created something similar: https://github.com/james-wasson/MewJS - BTW very cool project MaxCore